# Detect library features at runtime in C

Tags: c, shared-libraries, lazy-loading, ld

I am trying to build a program in C which has a lot of optional features that depend on various shared libraries.

In our heterogeneous computing cluster not all of those libraries are available (or up to date) on all systems.

Examples are symbols from newer glibc (`sched_getcpu@@GLIBC_2.6`, `__sched_cpucount@@GLIBC_2.6`) or whole shared libraries which may or may not be available (`libnuma`, `libR`, `libpbs`).

I know that I can use `libdl` to load the symbols with `dlopen` and `dlsym`, but doing this for an ever growing number of symbols (around 30 at the moment) is tedious at best.

As far as I understand shared libraries in Linux are lazy-loaded by default, so a symbol should not be needed until it is actually used.

But if I try to check for that in advance then it fails at execution start:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sched.h>

int main() {

    void *lib_handle;
    int (*fn)(void);
    int x;
    char *error;

    lib_handle = dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!lib_handle) 
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
       exit(1);
    }

    fn = dlsym(lib_handle, "sched_getcpu");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
       exit(1);
    }

    printf("%d\n", sched_getcpu());

    return 0;
}
```

On compile system which has all libraries:

```
$ icc test.c
$ ./a.out
10
```

On another system which has a less recent version of GLIBC:

```
$ ./a.out 
./a.out: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.6' not found (required by ./a.out)
```

If I comment out the line that actually calls `sched_getcpu` then I get instead on the lesser system:

```
$ ./a.out 
/lib64/libc.so.6: undefined symbol: sched_getcpu
```

So, is there a way to force libraries only to be loaded on use and have checks like these before blocks that use them?

Comment: It might be safer in the long run to try to make your cluster a wee bit more homogeneous.  Alternately the best solution is to static-link all your executables that must run on these inconsistently maintained systems, and hope that at least they run decently compatible kernels.  If your cluster were running a BSD, esp. NetBSD then this would be easy, provided you linked the app on the oldest version of the system running in the cluster.

Comment: @GregA.Woods This is what I keep telling my sysadmins. But the problem is: I am a software developer. I need to write code and have it run. I don't even have admin access to the cluster, so that's not an option. Kernels are all Linux, but it's a mixture of CentOS in different flavors on the low-power machines and RedHat on the supercomputers.

Comment: Then static linking is your best, and perhaps only, option.  You may have to build your own build machine to find a least-common-denominator kernel version though.  For most things it's not that hard to do either.

Comment: @GregA.Woods Some things can be statically linked, others like `libnuma` are very difficult to obtain a static version for. I would still prefer to detect missing libraries at run time since most features that require libraries are optional optimizations. e.g. a system that doesn't have `libnuma` won't need it since it's not NUMA in the first place, so those scheduling/memory optimizations won't make any sense there. The only three required libraries that I need are luckily `glibc`, `libpthread`, `libomp`. And luckily `icc` provides a static OpenMP library.

Comment: Perhaps if you compile everything from source then you'll have a better handle on how libraries are created.  I would _always_ do that anyway.  The only other alternative is to supply explicit copies of each shared library with your package install such that your package never depends on _any_ non-system library.  That may even include supplying your own `glibc` on GNU/Linux systems since I don't think Glibc does things correctly for some forms of backward compatibility.  Static linking is _ever_ so much easier though -- far fewer parts to break!

Answer (score 1):

Not with glibc. This is a fail-safe and it's in place so that you won't shoot yourself in the foot. If the `GLIBC_2.6` symbol wasn't defined and looked up, even if there were no other missing symbols, you could get garbage results from glibc (data corruption and crashes,) since it's not forwards compatible.

If you need compatibility on the glibc level, you need to build against the lowest common version.

Comment: OK, so I will have to manually load glibc symbols or use `syscall` directly. At the moment I am only incompatible with the two listed symbols. What about other libraries?

Comment: @SergeyL. Other libraries work as usual. If the definitions of the symbols you provide are compatible, they will work.